# Canned comment to use when reviewing a short answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is a request arising out of experience in reviewing low quality answers (it applies to questions too, but less so). Many of the common situations are well handled by canned comments: link only, spam, question masquerading, etc.

A common situation is a very short answer that may (or may not) be correct, but is certainly unhelpful to readers. It might be one line of code or one technical quote from a manual. It's not obviously wrong and it could even be perfectly correct but it's lazy, and it doesn't contribute to making SO a repository of high quality questions and answers. I've made comments on a few, but it's time consuming and unless I know the topic well enough I can't really improve the answer. But I don't want to let it pass.

My preference would be a canned comment selected by the review choice "answer too short" and mark for deletion. If it gets deleted, convert it to a comment. The author of the post would still be able to see the comment as to why it was deleted and hopefully will try harder next time.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4637905) an example.

<sup>*As always, if I'm on the wrong track or this is a duplicate, let me know in the time-honored way.*</sup>

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Answer (score 3):

When the answer merely states some opinion, I typically comment like as follows:

> without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like *"`<insert opposite opinion here>`"*, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to fit [answer] guidelines.

Above, [edit] and [answer] are [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-links) that transform into the link to edit the commented posts and [how to answer page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) after posting.

Comment: My beef is with super short answers lacking context or explanation. They may help the original questioner (or not), but they sure don't help any other readers. Thanks for the tips -- it's very hard to learn cute tricks for comments, not being able to see the markdown of the experts.

Comment: BTW the [answer] page implies that very short answers are OK, if not encouraged. Should it say something stronger, or am I out of step here?

Comment: @david.pfx I think you're out of step here (assuming SO, at Programmers or Workplace it could be different). You may try my _template_, using "do X" instead of "opinion" and "don't do X" instead of "opposite opinion", but it would be rather difficult to squeeze anything stronger than that

Comment: @gnat: Maybe put "good advice comes with a rationale" in there too?

Comment: [usage example (sort of)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269310/839601). @Deduplicator yeah I was thinking about something like that in the past, this would be appealing because it makes comment more friendly. However, in the end, I preferred to keep that out, for stylistic reasons: addition like this sounds like personal opinion, and it doesn't feel like mixing well with the objective tone of the rest of comment, and it doesn't feel right to use opinionated advice against opinionated answer