# Triage All Feature Requests, give an official position and timeline

Tags: discussion, triage, se-quality-project

I [grumped at @MartijnPieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289266/how-best-to-receive-a-new-answerer-who-is-wrong/289268?noredirect=1#comment172124_289268) about several problems.  He said talking to me wouldn't be productive *(I think lack of productivity can be a property of more than one party's attitude in a conversation...and I'm getting annoyed at having to mirror all my SO posts due to random deletion risk)*.

But he did suggest the [`se-quality-project`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project).  So here is one aspect of my concerns, regarding the `feature-request` tag.

On Meta.SO the tag has [1,658 entries](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

On Meta.SE the tag has [3,818 entries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There are status-* tags:

- `status-completed`
- `status-bydesign`
- `status-declined`
- `status-norepro`
- `status-deferred`
- `status-planned`
- `status-reproduced`

If you look only at the `status-*` tag counts, they actually look pretty favorable.  But when you start doing intersections with `feature-request` vs. "bug", the picture becomes a bit more grim.

From above, on Meta.SE there are 3,818 feature requests.  How many have been formally declined?  14.  How many have been completed?  60.  By design?  2.  There are 6 that were deferred, and 20 have been planned.

For Meta.SO the picture for the 1,658 is similar.  77 declined requests.  69 completed.  2 deferred.  1 planned.

Tags don't tell the whole story.  I'm sure someone with SE-data-explorer-fu can paint a more precise picture than that does.  But it is troubling to me, when there is a volunteer army of idea-givers providing suggestions, getting crickets on this stuff.

e.g. why is it--exactly--that an *easy* crowd-sourced idea with 52 votes (much easier to implement than hats or StackEgg) has never been given a fair shake, much less an administrative "we will or won't" or why?

[Pre-flight screening checklist for first/early posts--adaptively pick three items, tune with metrics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/pre-flight-screening-checklist-for-first-early-posts-adaptively-pick-three-item)

How is it that for over a year, a *trivial* suggestion on an 11 upvote post that [suggests fixed-width replies in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209731/allow-chat-messages-in-fixed-width-font-to-be-marked-as-replies)...hasn't been commented on, or said "why we won't/can't" or set any expectations?  The result is a kind of feeling of powerlessness, in a network service analog to the lamentations in ["Why Software Should Be Free"](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/shouldbefree.html).

I propose a time window under which all feature-requests be given a status, officially.  A month is a bit long, but we have to start somewhere...so how about that?  If declined, say why (hopefully as an answer so that it can be elaborated well enough to explain).  If planned, say more-or-less when and give people a way to bring it back up.  *(The bounty system has been killed on meta, so some option needs to be available for a `status-planned` that's overdue to bring it back up.)*

Comment: [Every feature request starts at -100](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx). If you insist on the dev team providing an official evaluation within a month, you will end up with lots of `[status-declined]` tags. Is that really your intent?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You've invoked something I've never heard of or seen.  I've never made a feature request and lost 100 points.  So your "-100" is some invisible thing out in "feature-request space".  If there is an invisible bookkeeping system it should become visible so people realize what's going on.  If there's enough time for inventing random new badges for games there's enough time to game the ticketing system and let people know what game they're playing.  In fact, that's an interesting idea: have SE turn features into a game, like the rest of it, with rule sets...nontraditional tracker.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Also, whatever -100 means, if it meant a question scoring thing, [Pre-Flight](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/) is 260.  What's the excuse?

Comment: I added a link to the rationale behind the -100. I wasn't referring to reputation or anything SO-specific, but to the initial weight of a given feature request when considered by its would-be implementors.

Comment: "you will end up with lots of `[status-declined]` tags. Is that really your intent?" That sounds pretty good to me, actually. A prompt "no" is better than indefinite ambiguous silence.

Comment: @Kevin I agree completely, but something about people in general is they don't care much for accountability.  How many people go forth putting the truth of the matter out when it might harm their situation?  Not so many.  SE devs will hate the idea of more work if there's nothing in it for them, regardless of the frustration of the volunteer army...remember [the truth](https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6170/6185789175_ea1bb782a7_o.jpg).  *(for an alternative, see [BlackHighlighter](http://blackhighlighter.hostilefork.com/)...)*

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40434/why-are-there-so-many-feature-request-with-no-official-response  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133080/when-will-a-feature-request-be-marked-as-either-status-completed-or-status-decli  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60505/why-dont-all-bugs-and-feature-requests-have-moderator-status-tags http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/why-dont-we-get-responses-from-bug-reports http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129279/how-long-is-a-normal-time-for-a-feature-request-to-be-approved-or-denied

Comment: Pardon me if I'm a bit dense here, but... Where are you getting "14" and "60" for declined and completed? I've *personally* declined and completed more than that.

Comment: @Shog9 Data comes from tag intersection queries, things like [`[feature-request] [status-completed]`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-completed)  Queries are dynamic and site-specific of course.  As I said, maybe someone else's fu is better than mine in the study here, but I was challenged about my assertion that the queue had piled up to the point where it seemed pointless to make suggestions... so I used what tools I had to make my case.

Answer (score 4):

Your concept of "simple" is both subjective and inaccurate, with respect to what the Stack Exchange devs are actually working on.

To be blunt, this is a terrible idea.  It will only lead to more feature requests being turned down which could otherwise be worked when they've got some time to do so.

A month is actually not long at all when you're mapping out future features of a site or a project, so I'm not confident that with that much time, the team would be able to objectively state whether or not they could work on it.

What would likely be a better approach is an automatic tombstoning mechanism, which retagged feature requests which haven't had enough attention in a while - say 6 months - with [status-tombstoned](/questions/tagged/status-tombstoned) instead.  This way, the feature isn't entirely *lost*, and the team can go back into the tombstoned backlog to prune it every now and then.

Comment: I inventoried status properties and [status-deferred](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred) is one of the options, marked *"This suggestion has merit, but it isn't the very next thing on our list. We'll try to get to it."*  Not as strong as planned, but still an active action.  I don't think one month is unreasonable to ask for deferral status.  It at least says "we think this idea has merit".  Some random 6-month status-tombstoned done through automation does not convey that.  This is a request for triage.

Comment: I personally think it is.  Development is an iceberg; you only ever see a little bit of the overall effort at any one time.  If you were to propose that the team divert their efforts into surfacing that iceberg in a month, that'd be unreasonable.  This is just experience speaking, but with a network as complex as Stack Exchange, *and* with all of the other stuff the team has to maintain (Careers, maintenance, etc), a month just *isn't enough time.*

Comment: This reminds me of people saying they're too busy to answer email.  If you have that much attention, you have "energy"... people willing to invest.  If people are beating down your door that hard, you can hire and delegate.  Hire and delegate someone with the responsibility to triage in O(1 month).

Comment: I'm not capable of speaking to the resources available to Stack Exchange, but it sounds incredibly wasteful to have someone who  is just going to comb through all user-submitted feature requests and leave a status update in a month.  Not just that, but I'm sure that their project/product managers are more than capable of picking off what they want to focus their energies on and what they don't all in their own pace.  The automatic tombstoning was a compromise to at least meet in the middle of the whole thing.  What you're asking for is simply untenable.

Comment: @Hostile, you know what? You should apply for a position on the dev team. Should you succeed, please come back to us in a year with your new thoughts on "attention" and "energy" :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If I were that devoted to correcting your (presumably you work there?) mistakes, then I'd do what Jeff and Joel did to expertsexchange and make a new site.  *Not in this lifetime*, I'm busy enough as is.  So I'm suggesting *simple* changes from within as a user.  Changing systems from within are difficult *(do you think Joel and Jeff would have succeeded with changing expertsexchange by working for them?)*  And where are Jeff and Joel now, exactly?  Trello and... retirement, I think.

Comment: @Hostile, heh, I don't work there, no. It does strike me as odd that you consider yourself as "busy enough", but deny the same privilege to other developers (presumably you are a developer?).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Nope, I'm a [fry cook at the Steak 'n Chik](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_dEtaNx2Vc).  *(To be fully honest, I don't understand where that leaves us.)*

Answer (score 3):

Currently, feature requests are a cookie jar that the developers can reach into whenever they want ideas.  If this proposal were implemented, the result would be that most proposals, even good ones, would be tagged as `status-rejected`.  The cookie jar would be emptied.  But why would developers do that?

With the list of tags shown in the proposal, the developers have only two choices for a feature request: planned, and declined.  "Planned" requires the developers to commit to doing it.  "Declined" requires them to commit to *not* doing it.  Think about this from a developer's point of view: This iteration is in progress, and the next one is probably already at least partially mapped out.  Now I have a limited time in order to tag the feature request.  "Planned" is the dangerous one, from a developer's point of view: I'm having to commit to doing something in the uncertain future.  If things change and I can't do it, I'll face the wrath of the community ("but you said you would do it!").  "Declined" is the safer option.  It may make some people unhappy now, but it not as unhappy as promising to do it and then having to renege.  That's why this proposal would result in the prompt emptying of the cookie jar.

Comment: in projects I participated developers had no problem using "will not fix" tickets as a cookie jar. Actually, it was rather convenient. You get to will not fix ticket, quickly find an evaluation of why it was considered unfeasible, check whether it still applies - and if not, pick it, update evaluation and fix

Comment: Well written, and analyzed. Couple of small things: 1) There is a [[status-review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-review)] tag, which indicates the team will look at the idea further and decide if they wish to do it or not. 2) There's no rule saying the team can't turn around and change their mind on previous [status-declined] decisions. Ditto for [status-planned] decisions.

Comment: @Kendra The thrust here is about triage to know you were heard.  No one likes sending mail and not getting a response *(and for the paranoid there is always [HellBanning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellbanning), which [Jeff said he didn't like](http://blog.codinghorror.com/suspension-ban-or-hellban/)...but who knows?)*  A timely status response helps make sure the system is working, and while "status-review" is non-ideal, *some* form of triage with game rules for how long things can stay in that status seems better.